# How to show specific columns in a table by d3.js

Tags: css, d3.js

I created a table by using d3.js on a csv file.Now I need to show some specific columns of the csv file (not all of them). This is my code:

```
     d3.text('../data/satra_capitalasset_v_projectcount_m_b_enddate_executet.csv',     function(data) {
     var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data).filter;


     var sampleHTML = d3.select("body")
    .append("table")
    .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
    .style("border", "2px black solid")

    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(parsedCSV)
    .enter().append("tr")
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d){return d;})
    .enter().append("td")
    .style("border", "1px black solid")
    .style("padding", "5px")
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color",    "aliceblue")})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white")})
    .text(function(d){return d;})
    .style("font-size", "12px");
});
```

and my data is as follows:

```
name   project   company   
a1       p1         c1   
a2       p2         c1  
a3       p3         c3
a4       p4         c1
```

Now I need to show 2 columns from above data in my table.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing this will help you.

```
.text(function(d){return d.name;})
```

This way you can refer to the specific column you want or even use:

```
.text(function(d){return (d.name+"\t"+d.company);})
```

Well hope you get the idea that you can refer to the headings of your data to do this.